# How does OS know to which process send a keyboard interrupt?

Tags: linux, operating-system, keyboard, linux-device-driver

Below is a simple c program (for Ubuntu OS) that waits for any keyboard key to be pressed and then terminates.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    while(true) {
        if (_kbhit()) {
            printf("Key hit\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I start this program on a terminal nr. 1, the program reacts to me pressing the keys only if the mouse is pointing to a terminal 1. Thus, if two such programs are running as separate processes at the same time, pressing a key will terminate at most one program.

**How does the OS know to which process send a keyboard interrupt?**

Comment: Your task must be connected to `stdin` to accept input from the keyboard.

Comment: So what? `stdin` is `FILE*` to my understanding. I can start a background process that reads from a file. Why reading from a keyboard requires the process to be at the "foreground"?

Comment: @mercury0114 ... because, in the case of multiple processes requesting keyboard input, the OS needs to know which process to send keyboard input to!  So, it keeps a record of the one  process that has focus - it is 'foreground'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big question.  In your example, as stated *it* doesn't; depending upon your definition of *OS*.

In a classic unix system, the GUI is provided by a relatively conventional program running in user space.  The GUI (eg. X11) is the only one connected to the actual keyboard device; and it translates those keys into *events* in the GUI.  When a key is pressed, whichever window in the GUI that has *input focus* will receive the event.

A *terminal emulator* is a program which runs within the GUI, providing programs with a 1970s tty interface to the GUI.  This program utilizes a special type of tty-device, called a pseudo-tty, which functions very much like a **pipe(2)** that supports the terminal specific functions (tc*, ioctl).  When the *terminal emulator* receives a GUI event indicating a key hit, it injects it into the pseudo-tty, which then provides it to the program as an ascii/utf-8 character.

The GUI chooses which window has focus for input events by configuration.  Some people prefer geographic -- which ever window the mouse pointer is in receives these events; some prefer *click to focus*, where you must click in a window to determine who has focus.  Both have advantages and disadvantages; but if you often receive strange messages in irc/slack/... from somebody, they likely chose click-to-focus.

In the absence of a gui, the answer is both easier and more intricate.  In the obvious case, it is the program printing the "$ " prompt at you; in the intricate case, you need to read up on **sessions, process groups, controlling terminals, job control**.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, here is a program that reads input directly from the keyboard buffer (a.k.a. keylogger):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/input.h>

int main() {
    // Note: on other computers path to a keyboard buffer might differ
    const char path[] = "/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd";
    FILE* keyboard_buffer = fopen(path, "r");
    if (keyboard_buffer == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open. Try running with root access.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    struct input_event event;
    while(1) {
        fread(&event, sizeof event, 1, keyboard_buffer);
        if (event.type == EV_KEY && event.value == 1) {
            printf("Key %d has been pressed\n", event.code);
            fclose(keyboard_buffer);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

If you start this program and press the key anywhere, it will exit immediately, because here we read keyboard data not from stdin, but from the keyboard buffer mounted on a file `/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd`

Your code, on the other hand, uses `conio.h` library to read a keyboard event, which internally calls `getchar()` to read from [stdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams):

> When a command is executed via an interactive shell, the streams (i.e. stdin) are typically connected to the text terminal on which the shell is running,

The stdin of one process will point to a different file than the stdin of another process.

Now what the OS (namely, a keyboard driver) does is it forwards a keypress from the keyboard buffer to the stdin of the foreground process. Since in your case, only one of the programs will be run as a foreground process, the key-press will be forwarded only to one of the stdin streams.